# Holomorphic function with given boundary values

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

I have a complex valued function on the boundary of a set, and want to know if it has a holomorphic extension to the entire set (holomorphic in interior, continuous up to the boundary).

In other words: Given a smooth open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$, and a smooth complex-valued function $f:\partial\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$, when does there exist a function $u \in C(\bar{\Omega})$ which is holomorphic in the interior and such that $u(z)=f(z)$ for any $z \in \partial\Omega$?

This came up in research.  I'm studying a free boundary problem on the region $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|y\leq h(x)\}$ (assume $h$ smooth to keep things simple) and have a vector field $(x,h(x)) \mapsto [1,h'(x)]$ which is tangent to the free surface.  It would be very helpful if I could extend that vector field to the entire domain (or at least some subdomain, e.g. $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|y\in (h(x)-\varepsilon,h(x)]\}$) while satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  Unfortunately I haven't thought about complex analysis in about a decade.

Comment: The result, given the regularity of the boundary of $\Omega$ is classical: you'll find it, for example, in the reference cited in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369673/periods-of-the-harmonic-conjugate-and-a-dirichlet-problem-on-a-multiply-connecte/371556#371556). But there are many sources (both textbooks and monograph) which offer a solution of this boundary problem.

Comment: My boundary function has both real and imaginary parts.  I know how to/when I can find the unique real function $u$ so that $u=\Re(f)$ on $\partial\Omega$, and the unique real function $v$ so that $v = \Im(f)$ on $\partial\Omega$, which is what the text you referenced seems to deal with.  My question is whether $u+iv$ is holomorphic, and what criterion on $f$ predicts this outcome.  It's possible/likely this is an elementary question, but I can't find anything relevant in the text your referenced